# создать принтер из командной строки

Tags: linux, gnu, cups

создать принтер (точнее, очередь печати) можно, например, с помощью встроенного в *cups* веб-интерфейса — `http://localhost:631` (или каким-нибудь gui-конфигуратором).

а как это сделать из командной строки? для автоматизации этого процесса, например.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

«штатное» средство, идущее в комплекте с набором программ, именуемым для краткости *cups*, называется *lpadmin* (в *debian*-основных дистрибутивах входит в пакет [*cups-client*](https://packages.debian.org/search?keywords=cups-client&searchon=names&exact=1&suite=all&section=all)).

для создания/модификации очереди печати служит такая форма запуска этой программы:

```
$ lpadmin -p имя_очереди [разные опции]
```

(есть ещё две формы: удаления очереди — `lpadmin -x имя_очереди`, и назначение очереди по умолчанию — `lpadmin -d имя_очереди`).

если указанной очереди ещё не было — она создаётся. если уже была, то этой командой можно изменить опции существующей очереди.

запускаться программа должна либо от имени пользователя, входящего в группу, которой разрешено администрирование *cups-а* (обычно — `lpadmin`), тогда, вероятно, надо будет указать полный путь к ней — `/usr/sbin/lpadmin`, либо от имени пользователя *root* (т.е., например, с использованием `sudo`: `sudo lpadmin ...`).

«минимальный джентльменский набор» `разных опций`, пожалуй, можно свести к такому списку:

- `-E` — сразу сделать очередь доступной (эта опция, если её употребить **до** опций `-p`/`-d`/`-x` означает совсем другое — «использовать шифрование при подлючении к *cups*-серверу». ну, такие вот выдумщики эти разработчики)
- `-v uri-принтера` — *uri*, по которому доступен принтер. для «сетевых», поддерживающих спецификацию «hp jetdirect», это что-нибудь вроде `socket://сетевое.имя:9100` (подробнее про [«сетевые» *uri*](https://www.cups.org/doc/network.html))
- `-o media=A4` — iso-формат бумаги («европейский»). лучше указать явно, чтобы не нарваться на «североамериканский» (см. про [*letter*](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Letter) и [*a4*](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/A4))
- `-m uri-фильтра` или `-P /путь/к/файлу/с/фильтром` — см. примечание

всё вместе:

```
$ lpadmin -p имя_очереди -E -v uri-принтера -o media=A4 -m uri-фильтра
```

или:

```
$ lpadmin -p имя_очереди -E -v uri-принтера -o media=A4 -P /путь/к/файлу/с/фильтром
```

---

#### примечание про фильтры

*cups* позволяет, для адаптации задания печати под конкретную модель принтера, пропустить задание через фильтр — так называемый [*postscript printer description*](https://www.cups.org/doc/man-lpadmin.html), сокращённо *ppd* (отсюда и знакомые многим суффиксы `.ppd` у файлов с такими фильтрами).

теоретически, если принтер достаточно «интеллектуален», в качестве *uri-фильтра* можно указать `raw`: `-m raw`. в [документации](https://www.cups.org/doc/man-lpadmin.html) по этому поводу написано так:

> The model "raw" clears any existing PPD file and the model "everywhere" queries the printer referred to by the specified IPP device-uri.

но обычно фильтр (*ppd*) указывают явно, [выбирая производителя, а затем модель принтера](http://www.openprinting.org/printers). это если очередь создаётся из веб-интерфейса или с помощью gui-конфигуратора. а в случае командной строки всё это разнообразие можно посмотреть командой:

```
$ lpinfo -m
```

программа `lpinfo` тоже может располагаться в `/usr/sbin`, тогда придётся указать к ней полный путь.

пример вывода для псевдо-модели `HP LaserJet 6P`:

```
$ lpinfo --make-and-model 'HP LaserJet 6P' -m
gutenprint.5.2://hp-lj_6p/expert HP LaserJet 6P - CUPS+Gutenprint v5.2.9
foomatic:HP-LaserJet_6P-lj4dith.ppd HP LaserJet 6P Foomatic/lj4dith
foomatic:HP-LaserJet_6P-ljet4.ppd HP LaserJet 6P Foomatic/ljet4
drv:///hpijs.drv/hp-laserjet_6p-hpijs.ppd HP LaserJet 6p hpijs, 3.12.6
drv:///hpcups.drv/hp-laserjet_6p.ppd HP LaserJet 6p, hpcups 3.12.6
postscript-hp:0/ppd/hplip/HP/hp-laserjet_6mp-ps.ppd HP LaserJet 6P/6MP - PostScript
postscript-hp:1/ppd/hplip/HP/hp-laserjet_6mp-ps.ppd HP LaserJet 6P/6MP - PostScript
```

из него можно взять, например, пятую строку и использовать в качестве *uri-фильтра* при вызове *lpadmin*: `-m drv:///hpcups.drv/hp-laserjet_6p.ppd`

также нередко случается, что нужно использовать уже «готовый» фильтр, хранящийся в файле с суффиксом `.ppd`. тогда и надо применять опцию `-P /путь/к/файлу.ppd` (вместо `-m uri-фильтра`).

---

вышеописанное, в принципе, должно подойти не только к операционной системе *gnu/linux*, но и, например, к *apple/macosx*.

---

вероятно, стоит ещё упомянуть про то, как посмотреть список доступных очередей печати:

```
$ lpstat -a
```

немного в другом виде:

```
$ lpstat -v
```