# Где лежат ppd файлы в современных дистрибутивах?

Tags: linux, debian, печать, cups

Дебиан 10. Хочу установить принтер с консоли через lpadmin. Тут нужно указать ppd файл (конкретно pcl5e). Не могу их найти, хотя в графическом интерфейсе всё есть.

модель в интерфейсе `Generic PCL 5e Printer Foomatic/hpijs-pcl5e`

Есть вот `/usr/share/cups/drv/hpijs.drv` и `/usr/share/cups/ppd-updaters/printer-driver-hpijs.ppd-updater` . Как им пользоваться? - нашел, не то.

```
LANG=en_US ppdc -d myppds /usr/share/cups/drv/*drv
```

нет нужного.

Онлайн генератор https://www.openprinting.org/driver/hpijs-pcl5e/ выдает то что нужно, но как получить ppd локально?

Comment: `/usr/share/ppd/`, не?

Comment: @Fat-Zer нет там ничего. только залётные hpfax

Comment: Сперва надо «драйвер» принтера из репозитория установить, не? У меня вот установлен `hplip`  и в папочке `/usr/share/ppd/HP/` лежат всякие ppd

Comment: Ну а вообще `find /etc /usr -iname '*.ppd*'`

Comment: в /usr/share/ppd/HP/ лежат всякие ppd - не много их там, да и не те что нужно.

Comment: нет ничего в нужного find /etc /usr

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> модель в интерфейсе `Generic PCL 5e Printer Foomatic/hpijs-pcl5e`

в каталоге `/usr/lib/cups/driver` имеется скрипт с самораспаковывающимся архивом файлов *ppd* из базы данных *foomatic*. аргументы, которые приемлет скрипт:

```
$ /usr/lib/cups/driver/foomatic-db-compressed-ppds
Usage: foomatic-db-compressed-ppds list
       foomatic-db-compressed-ppds cat URI

foomatic-db-compressed-ppds: error: incorrect number of arguments
```

фильтруем список на предмет нужной модели:

```
$ /usr/lib/cups/driver/foomatic-db-compressed-ppds list | grep 'Generic PCL 5e Printer Foomatic/hpijs-pcl5e'
"foomatic-db-compressed-ppds:0/ppd/foomatic-ppd/Generic-PCL_5e_Printer-hpijs-pcl5e.ppd" en "Generic" "Generic PCL 5e Printer Foomatic/hpijs-pcl5e (recommended)" "MFG:Generic;MDL:PCL 5e Printer;DRV:Dhpijs-pcl5e,R1,M0,Sv,TI,X600,Y600,C0,t100,l100,g100,p100,s70;"
```

первая подстрока — это *uri* требующегося нам *ppd*. запросим *ppd* и сохраним в файл:

```
$ /usr/lib/cups/driver/foomatic-db-compressed-ppds cat "foomatic-db-compressed-ppds:0/ppd/foomatic-ppd/Generic-PCL_5e_Printer-hpijs-pcl5e.ppd" > наш.ppd
```

да, получили действительно ppd:

```
$ file наш.ppd 
наш.ppd: PPD file, version "4.3"
```

---

насколько я понимаю, все файлы из этого каталога (`/usr/lib/cups/driver`) предназначены для извлечения файлов «на лету», по требованию:

```
$ apt-file search /usr/lib/cups/driver
cups-filters-core-drivers: /usr/lib/cups/driver/driverless
foomatic-db-compressed-ppds: /usr/lib/cups/driver/foomatic-db-compressed-ppds
foomatic-db-engine: /usr/lib/cups/driver/foomatic
hpijs-ppds: /usr/lib/cups/driver/hpijs-ppds
hplip: /usr/lib/cups/driver/hplip
hplip-data: /usr/lib/cups/driver/hplip-data
openprinting-ppds: /usr/lib/cups/driver/openprinting-ppds
printer-driver-dymo: /usr/lib/cups/driver/dymo
printer-driver-escpr: /usr/lib/cups/driver/escpr
printer-driver-foo2zjs-common: /usr/lib/cups/driver/foo2zjs
printer-driver-fujixerox: /usr/lib/cups/driver/fujixerox
printer-driver-gutenprint: /usr/lib/cups/driver/gutenprint.5.3
printer-driver-m2300w: /usr/lib/cups/driver/m2300w
printer-driver-postscript-hp: /usr/lib/cups/driver/postscript-hp
printer-driver-ptouch: /usr/lib/cups/driver/ptouch
printer-driver-pxljr: /usr/lib/cups/driver/pxljr
```

Comment: [доп. информация](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/624849/178576)

Comment: а нет ли какой команды чтоб по всем драйверам сделать `list`  и `cat` ?

Comment: `lpinfo --make-and-model 'HP LaserJet 6P' -m ` вот, то чно нужно

Comment: можно взять исходные файлы: http://deb.debian.org/debian/pool/main/f/foomatic-db/foomatic-db_20181217.orig.tar.xz

Answer (score 0):

Качать ppd с интернета как-то странно и неуютно...

```
wget -O /tmp/pcl5e.ppd 'https://www.openprinting.org/ppd-o-matic.php?driver=hpijs-pcl5e&printer=Generic-PCL_5e_Printer&.submit=Generate+PPD+file&show=0&.cgifields=show&.cgifields=shortgui' 

lpadmin -p `hostname` -v socket://192.168.76.22 -P /tmp/pcl5e.ppd
```

Правильный вариант

```
lpinfo --make-and-model "Generic PCL 5e" -m

lpadmin -p `hostname` -v socket://192.168.76.22 -m 'foomatic-db-compressed-ppds:0/ppd/foomatic-ppd/Generic-PCL_5e_Printer-hpijs-pcl5e.ppd'
```