# Как установить драйвера для deskjet 1510 series с помощью командной строки для RHEL8?

Tags: драйвер

Как установить драйвера для deskjet 1510 series  с помощью командной строки для RHEL8?

Comment: разве пакета cups недостаточно?

Comment: может быть, вам просто [очередь печати](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/624849/178576) нужна?